# Wordpress site header content won't display on Samsung tablet

Tags: css, wordpress

I am looking at [the site I am working on](http://ovionpartners.karencurrydesign.com/) on a Samsung tablet and am having a problem with the header.

The company logo, header widget and navigation have disappeared. Wordpress is only displaying the text site title in it's place.

I'm guessing that the issue lies in the media queries, but I'm not sure how to target the device and tell it to display content as it's supposed to.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take note of the [guidelines for questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and provide us with the relevant code (CSS/HTML). Without that, even if we can help you it's of no value to future visitors, especially as your linked site may change or cease to exist.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. Here is the css:

https://gist.github.com/nihaokitty/f22e73c658c6a8945a3c